# Remove current subview ios

Tags: ios, cocoa, uibutton, subview

I have an app that when loads, loads a tab based app whereby all tabs work fine. In the first tab however the view loaded has a whole bunch of buttons. I have written methods of these buttons so when pressed they push a new subview (.xib) and this works fine.

However, when in these new subviews I have a back button which has its own method. I want this button to remove the view and return back to the orignal view. Here is the code from FirstViewController.m.

Bear in mind that this File holds all the code even though it handles different .xib files. basically it pushes FirstView first, then when button is pressed it will push `E87view.xib`, the code for the .xib is still within the firstviewcontroller file.

```
-(IBAction) backButtonPressed {
    [self showAll];
    backButton.hidden = 1;

    for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self showAll];
}

-(IBAction) E87Pressed {
    //[self hideAll];

    E87view *e87view = [[E87view alloc] initWithNibName:@"E87view" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:e87view animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:e87view.view];
}
```

So just to reiterate, when i press the button E87 on the first view that's loaded `FirstView.xib` it will push the new view `E87view.xib`. However when I press the back button on this newly loaded `E87view` it will access the above function and remove the view but also remove all the setup I had from `FirstView.xib` essentially leaving me with an empty app.

Hope this makes sense I can ramble a bit.

Regards,

Lewis

Comment: In the text you are saying, that you used a tab controller. And you code says you are using a navigation controller. Are you using the navigation controller in one tab or is the tab controller a mistake?

Comment: No it is a tabbed app and the delegate does have a tabBarController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing every individual subviews, just remove the ViewController from the navigation controller using

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
```

And this line is unnecessary

```
[self.view addSubview:e87view.view];
```

Comment: I am assuming you mean to add the line

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];

to the back button? It doesnt work. And the addsubview line is what brings that view to the front when e87 is pressed.

Comment: You really doesn't need to add e87view.view as a subview, the navigation controller will display the viewController's view once pushViewController:animated: is called. Same thing happen when you call popViewControllerAnimated:, it will revert to the preview viewController view. If it doesn't work, the problem may come from elsewhere.

Comment: Right I think our wires are getting crossed. My FirstViewController file holds all code for all buttons on FirstView.xib and for every view I will want to bring up in its place such as e87view.xib. The line,  

    [self.view addSubview:e87view.view]; , 

Brings the subview e87view to the front, which is blank with only a back button. The back button should remove that view. How do I remove that view? The back button is a button I put there a UIButton which is connected to the above function in FirstViewController.

Comment: You could add a Tag to the new subview and remove that specific view using 
self.View.ViewWithTag(100).RemoveFromSuperview();

Comment: I tried to add a tag but I dont know how. I might just record a video and post it here to explain what I mean. Saying that, E87view does have its own .h and .m files so maybe I should implement the back button code in there? Driving me nuts this is, damn you apple why not just use C++ :(

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, somethings confuse me:

1) Why are you adding the subview of viewController e87view to the main view again *after* pushing the view controller to the screen? Upon pushing viewController e87view, every thing should be handled for you.  The viewController will be added to the navigationController stack, and that viewControler's view should also be presented.

So calling

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:e87view animated:YES];
```

after

```
[self.view addSubview:e87view.view];
```

will add your view twice to the screen.

2)  Why are you writing your own code to navigate back? Although this *can* be done.. are you sure that's what you wish to do? Usually after pushing the viewController e87view to the navigationController, a back button will automatically appear for you **if** your viewController e87view has a **title**.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The code i posted is two different functions. One applies to the E87 button and the other to a back button that appears on a different view. If I comment out the line [self.view addSubview:e87view.view] then when I press the E87 button nothing happens. 

Essentially when I leave it there, that is the line that brings the E87view.xib to the front. On this new xib I bring to the front I have added another UIButton, this button is connected to the first function in my post. I just want it to remove the view and return back to the original view.

Comment: Help me understand this.  So this code you have above, it is contained in the **firstViewController** file and.. that firstViewController is the viewController that is loaded when you click on say.. the first Tab?  And.. that backButtonPressed method handles the unloading of each of the new views that's loaded from one of the buttons of firstViewController?

Comment: Something like that haha I am confusing things I think, forgive me. Right what I have done now is declare and implement the back button in the E87view.h/.m. I have added a UIButton to the E87view.xib. 

Right so that is that. When the app launches it brings up MainWindow.xib and FirstView.xib with the code behind handled by FirstViewController class. In this class when I press the UIButton E87 it pushes the E87view.xib to the screen (maintaining the tabs), and on this xib I have another UIButton linked to the backButtonPressed function which I just moved to the E87view class.

Comment: But when I press this back button on the E87view (class and xib) it doesnt do anything even though I have the code,

-(IBAction) backButtonPressed0{

 [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 
  //for (UIView *subview in [self.view subviews]) {
  
  
  //[subview removeFromSuperview];
  
  //}
 
}

Comment: Does somebody just want to skype me for a second? I can stream my desktop I'm sure I am doing something very stupid here. Objective C is still a new area for me. Hell, using a MAC is new to me.